# raspberry pi 3 static ip not working for direct ethernet-hardware connection

Tags: linux, ip, raspberry-pi, raspbian

My Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie is connected to external hardware via a direct ethernet connection.

In order to connect between the two devices, I believe the RasPi needs a static ip address on eth0. I already know the address of the external hardware: 192.168.1.158.

When I edit the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file to include the following:

```
interface eth0

static ip_address = 192.168.1.100/24
static routers = 192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
```

And /etc/network/interfaces has its default settings:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

I still get a bad eth0 ip address of 169.xxx.xxx.xx after rebooting and running sudo ifconfig.

Any suggestions? I previously tried editing the /etc/network/interfaces file so that  iface eth0 inet manual is instead iface eth0 inet static and then set the address from there. Running sudo ifconfig gave me the proper IP address when I tried that but I still was not able to ping the device properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. For a basic static IP configuration, you want something like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

After you have modified the file, you can then `ifdown eth0` and `ifup eth0` which should apply the static IP address. Verify by checking `ifconfig eth0`.

If you get the correct IP address but still cannot ping the device then you will need to confirm that ICMP echo requests are accepted by the server you are trying to ping.

Comment: I modified the file as suggested with the address 192.168.1.100. if config shows that eth0 now has the correct address but when I ping the eternal hardware I get "Destination Host Unreachable". This also happens when I connect the pi to my PC.

Comment: Have you verified that there is no firewall blocking ICMP traffic on either your Pi or target devices?